# no such table: tbcarro

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Após seguir alguns exemplos, estou com duvida sobre o seguinte erro:

```
11-24 20:49:14.803 18215-18215/tiburski.rg.cadastrocarro E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nome=ggggg modelo=ggggg placa=hhhh
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbcarro (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tbcarro(nome,modelo,placa) VALUES (?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
```

De acordo com alguns exemplos já criados, seguem as classes responsáveis pelo banco de dados.

```java
public class DataModal {

    private static final String DB_NOME = "carro.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSAO = 4;

    private static final String TBL_CARRO = "tbcarro";
    private static final String COLUNA_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUNA_NOME = "nome";
    private static final String COLUNA_PLACA = "placa";
    private static final String COLUNA_MODELO = "modelo";

    public static final String[] COLUNAS = {COLUNA_ID, COLUNA_NOME, COLUNA_PLACA, COLUNA_MODELO};

    public static String criarTabela() {
        String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ getTblCarro() +" ( "
                + getColunaId() +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + getColunaNome() +" VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
                + getColunaPlaca() +" VARCHAR UNSIGNED NULL, "
                + getColunaModelo() +" VARCHAR UNSIGNED NULL ); ";
        return CREATE_TABLE;
    }



    public static String getDbNome() {
        return DB_NOME;
    }

    public static int getDbVersao() {
        return DB_VERSAO;
    }

    public static String getTblCarro() {
        return TBL_CARRO;
    }

    public static String getColunaId() {
        return COLUNA_ID;
    }

    public static String getColunaNome() {
        return COLUNA_NOME;
    }

    public static String getColunaPlaca() {
        return COLUNA_PLACA;
    }

    public static String getColunaModelo() {
        return COLUNA_MODELO;
    }
```

```java
public class DataSource extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        super(context, DataModal.getDbNome(), null, DataModal.getDbVersao());
        mDb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DataModal.criarTabela());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

Outros exemplos com o código basicamente parecidos funcionam corretamente. Entretanto, neste exemplo está ocorrendo o erro mencionado. Poderiam me apontar aonde esta a falha ou as falhas no código?

Mais um ponto importante é que neste exemplo, na classe de persistência, inseri um novo método, o qual ainda não havia utilizado até então.

```java
private Context mContext;
    private static Persistencia mInstance;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public static Persistencia getmInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Persistencia.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new Persistencia(context);
                    mDb = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DataModal.getDbNome(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private Persistencia(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

Comment: Tenta utilizar um Log.i() depois de gerar os SQL e ve exatamente o que esta sendo executado e posta aqui, as vezes voce ta com algum erro de concatenacao que no olho nu esta passando batido. Consegue postar aqui exatamente qual SQL ta sendo executado?

Answer (score 1):

segundo o link ao lado -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554269/android-sqlite-no-such-table-error o erro é o seguinte:

existe uma versão antiga do banco de dados em seu dispositivo que faz o app achar que não existe o banco de dados. se for isso mesmo, a solução é desinstalar e reinstalar do zero o banco de dados.

Comment: Sobre a duvida que havia postado, segue link o qual me auxiliou, e que pode vir a auxiliar mais pessoas -> https://androiddevbr.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/sqlite-banco-de-dados-no-android/